# Infinite loop on the currency symbol alt key code 0164

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, symbols

In my sript I use

```
   If Selection.Text Like "* [aAwWzZiIoOuUVQ] *"
```

but if script check a table falls into infinite loop on the currency symbol alt key code 0164.
I use MsgBox Selection.Text and loops on such a line (and similar with marks 0164):
[image: table]
MsgBox show:
[image: MSgBox text]

How to skip checking such a line in the table, go further in the code or exit the For Next loop.
Something like:
If Selection.Text = ChrW(164) Then

[EDIT]
Ok my fault.
This is 7 lines not 1.
And selected text is not ChrW(164) but NOTHING.
I try If Selection.Text = "" Then
or
If Selection.Text = ChrW(0) Then
but loop not stop.

Comment: Difficult to suggests any fixes without the rest of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT2]

```
   Dim NumLines As Long     
       Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
NumLines = Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines)
  MsgBox "Lines to check " & (NumLines) & " If you want STOP: Press CTRL+Pause Break"
  Selection.Collaps
For i = 1 To NumLines...
```

Now I understand where the mistake is.
The macro did not loop indefinitely, even though it seemed to. It didn't hang on any particular character, it simply counted each table cell as a separate line and took that value as the final digit of the loop counter.